How to correctly configure RsBuild and Module Federation v2 to work with React and statically served assets
I'm trying to configure a POC with RsBuild and Module Federation v2. The goal is to have two React application one remote and one host where both will have nested routes with React Router.
I followed both RsBuild Documentation and Module Federation and I ended up with the below configuration, however the problem that arises is when introducing nested routes on remote.
For example, if I visit http://localhost:3001/some where some is a dynamic route everything works fine and I can also navigate to nested routes like http://localhost:3001/some/route1. However, when I hit refresh on /some/route1 the application breaks as the browser tries to load static files from http://localhost:3001/some instead of http://localhost:3001!
Now if I tweak the rspack publicPath from auto to / the remote will work as expected and the above behavior won't exist, but the host will break as it won't be able to locate the static files of the remote!
Why does the application work as expected with publicPath: auto with single routes but breaks once introducing nested routes?
rsbuild.config.js.
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        pluginReact({splitChunks: {react: false, router: false}}),
        pluginSass({
            sassLoaderOptions: {
                sassOptions: {
                    silenceDeprecations: ['import', 'global-builtin', 'abs-percent', 'color-functions', 'mixed-decls'],
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    html: {
        template: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'public/index.html'),
    },
    server: {
        port: 3001,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
        historyApiFallback: {
            rewrites: [
                {from: /./, to: '/index.html'}, // Redirect all paths to index.html
            ],
        },
    },
    tools: {
        rspack: {
            plugins: [
                new ModuleFederationPlugin(mfConfig),
            ],
            output: {
                publicPath: 'auto'
            },

        },
    },
    output: {
        distPath: {
            root: 'build',
        },
    },
}

mfconfig for remote is:
module.exports = {
    name: 'remote',
    filename:'remoteAppEntry.js',
    exposes: {
        './button': './src/button.tsx',
        './getItem': './src/util.ts',
    },
    shared: ['react', 'react-dom'],
    runtimePlugins: [require.resolve('./offline-remote.js')],
}

Host uses a dynamic way of fetching remotes.
I have created 2 repos one for host and one for remote that can be used to reproduce the issue.
